# Java Volleyball scoring program arrays and loops

Tags: java, arrays, iteration

I am new to coding. Please be gentle with me.
I have been charged with creating a program that compares the scores of two competing volleyball. To win a match in volleyball, a team must get 25 points. But the team must also win by 2. These two teams are going to play five matches.

The program should accept from the user the scores for each team one match at a time. If at any time that user enters scores that violate the 25-point rule or the “win by 2” point rule, print an error on the screen and make the user enter both scores again.

When the user is finished entering the scores, print which team won the game, that is the team that won the most matches.

You have to use arrays and loops in this assignment.

**My program is only scoring the first set of scores in the array.**
**How do I make it store all five sets of scores?**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int team1[];
        int team2[];
        team1=new int[5];
        team2=new int[5];
        int counter1=0;
        int counter2=0;
        int k = 0;


        for (int i=0;i<=4;i++){       
        Scanner scanint = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of points Team 1 earned in Match " + (i+1));
        team1[i] = scanint.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of points Team 2 earned in Match " + (i+1));
        team2[i] = scanint.nextInt();

////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (team1[i] < 25 & team2[i] < 25){
            System.out.println("That cannot be. One team must get at least 25 points. Please re-enter the data.");
            System.out.println("Enter the number of points Team 1 earned in Match " + (i+1));
        team1[i] = scanint.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of points Team 2 earned in Match " + (i+1));
        team2[i] = scanint.nextInt();
        }



        else if (team1[i] - team2[i] < 2 || team2[i] - team1[i] < 2){
           System.out.println("That can't be. One team must win by at least two points. Please re-enter the data.");
            System.out.println("Enter the number of points Team 1 earned in Match " + (i+1));
        team1[i] = scanint.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of points Team 2 earned in Match " + (i+1));
        team2[i] = scanint.nextInt();
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of points Team 1 earned in Match " + (i+1));
        team1[i] = scanint.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of points Team 2 earned in Match " + (i+1));
        team2[i] = scanint.nextInt();
        }


        /////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (team2[i] < team1[i]){
           counter1++;}
       else{ counter2++;}

    }
     if (counter1 > counter2)  {
      System.out.println("Team 1 has won the game.");}
      else{
              System.out.println("Team 2 has won the game.");
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are only a few rules for finished games that I see:

- Neither team can have negative points.
- At least one team has to have 25 or more points.
- The points for a team can't be above 25 unless it's exactly two points above or below the other team.

So, how do we do this? With some `if` statements for each rule. For the first rule:

```java
if ((team1 < 0) || (team2 < 0)) {
    System.err.println("A score cannot be negative!");
    i--;
    continue;
}
```

For the second rule:

```java
if ((team1 < 25) && (team2 < 25)) {
    System.err.println("At least one team has to have 25 or more points!");
    i--;
    continue;
}
```

For the third rule (this can be converted into one `if` statement with an `&&`, but I've made it a bit simpler to understand):

```java
if ((team1 > 25) || (team2 > 25)) {
    if ((team1 - team2 != 2) && (team2 - team1 != 2)) {
        System.err.println("If a team has more than 25 points, the other team must be two points away from it!");
        i--;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Note that the `continue;` means to go to the next iteration of the loop you're in. So, you go to the previous iteration with `i--;` and you go to the next iteration with `continue;`. This is a trick to allow you to restart the current iteration of the loop you're in.

---

Also, I wouldn't use arrays unless I used the scores somewhere outside the initial data input loop (though you should follow the rules for the assignment and use them anyway). I'd immediately point out when a game's scores were invalid and I'd keep track of the wins for both teams in some variables, like `int team1Wins = 0;` and `int team2Wins = 0;`.

Comment: Hey Chai, Just wanted to note I think she might be using the arrays to store the game scores. Possibly to look them up later.

Comment: @bsheps That's a good point, and I've added it to the answer.